# Why does Barbie feel like she’s in water when there’s no water coming out of the shower?

Tags: barbie-2023

Here is the scene from *Barbie* (2023), where Barbie turns on the shower, yet no water comes out. Strangely enough, she still experiences the sensation of being drenched in water:

[image]

Why does Barbie feel like she’s in water when there’s no water coming out of the shower?

Comment: She is playacting.  Just like the young girls do when, for example, they play at having a tea party.

Comment: "*Imagination, life is [her] creation.*"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Barbie acts *like a real Barbie would if she were being controlled by a little girl playing with her Barbie set*. Most of the mundane rules of our world simply don't apply, because they [don't apply when children are playing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEHuFcia6fw).

It's repeatedly stated in the [screenplay](https://8flix.com/assets/screenplays/b/tt1517268/Barbie-2023-screenplay.pdf) that her world is one of wonder. We marvel at the magic that is her life, where she doesn't actually need to use toothpaste and her breakfast consists of 'nothing', etc etc.

> Barbie Margot wakes up in her pink Dreamhouse. Everything is perfect.
> Of course. This whole sequence is like a moviemusical of the best life
> ever.
>
> There are no walls just like the toy so Barbie Margot can wave across
> to another Barbie waking up in her Dreamhouse next door.
>
> In every OTHER Dreamhouse, all the Barbies are having their perfect
> morning. It’s a Barbie Ballet.
>
> INT. BARBIE DREAMHOUSE. BATHROOM. DAY: Barbie Margot steps out of her
> heels, revealing her permanently arched feet.
>
> Barbie Margot stands under the shower head, but nothing comes out, she
> turns her head this way and that, as if there is water but there is
> nothing. Her hair looks amazing anyway.
>
> She opens an AMAZING closet and then magically steps out with a new,
> perfect outfit!